# Lost in how to start learning databases with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I was developing a website and learning how to code at the same time. So far I just got the hang of PHP. And now i want to learn how to integrate databases with PHP. Do i start learning MySQL and its libraries? I've been reading that PDO are the way to go and I'm just lost on what order I should be learning things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql is a database. Completely different thing. One is supposed to learn basic Mysql separately, independently from PHP or any other language, practicing basic queries in console or whatever GUI client.

Once you make yourself familiar with basic SQL, you can turn to running basic queries from PHP using PDO. Only static queries without variable parts.

And finally, you may start for building dynamical queries using **prepared statements**. Basic info on PDO you can find here in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Answer (score 0):

You have a very open-ended question.

However, typically with PHP the standard is MySQL so I would suggest you learn that.  Furthermore, most SQL is similar in syntax.  Typically when working in PHP you will use MySQL, PostgreSql or SQLlight.  They all have very similar syntax.

I suggest you find a book on PHP/MySQL and study that.  I typically don't endorse books, but there is a great book for beginners by Head First called, "Head First PHP & MySQL".  You will learn a lot with that book, you can google it as I don't know the link.

Furthermore, php.net is your best resource for PHP-related programming.

One final tip, I suggest you learn the Object-oriented way to program in general including opening your database connection as procedural-style is going away.

Good luck! And I am happy you are going with PHP and aren't another .net drone.

(also, download cake.php or codeignighter to learn about building lightweight, well-designed frameworks)

Comment: You bring up a interesting topic  to me. Should i be learning .net instead would it help me in the future in landing a job?

Comment: I am fluent in PHP, C# .net, and many others, as-of-yet PHP has been the highest-paying.  Easiest to get entry-level into is .net though.  Not gonna lie.  I much prefer PHP though and would recommend it to anyone. Majority of Fortune 500 companies use PHP somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would start in following order:

1. Create basic table and input some value through phpmyadmin

   *example: do one for users. create table named "user" and columns "user_id","username","password", "email"*
2. Use SELECT statements to select certain data through phpmyadmin
3. Build simple php page with connection and retrieve your db data
4. Learn about SQL injections and security issues learn Object Oriented Programming for PDO use (optional)
5. Start transferring your traditional mysql into PDO type

and then start learning mysql more in depth

Good Luck!

Comment: I wouldnt call PDO use optional. But rather obligatory

Comment: It was a typo, that part was referred to previous step. I meant to say, learning OOP before PDO is optional, because it will help him with understanding structure of PDO.